# Porting python app to silverlight or flash

Tags: python, flash, silverlight

I guess that title is self-explanatory.  Is there any such effort been made?

Some more info:

it's client application (gui intensive)

By porting I was thinking of cross-compiling.

Comment: Are you asking whether anyone's written a way to use the interactive Python interpreter via flash/SL?

Comment: "I guess that title is self-explanatory." -- Not really. Do you want a tool that converts Python code to ActionScript/C#? Do you want a way to run Python code inside Silverlight/Flash? What do you want?

Comment: What kind of an application is it? If it is a server side app created in Python, it is very likely that you cannot port it into a client side technology (for example Flex/Flash, Silverlight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the two, porting to Silverlight is going to be much easier.  You can target IronPython and focus primarily on changing/replacing the libraries that you've used in your Python app that aren't available in IronPython.

"Porting" to Flash would be more reasonably written as "rewriting a Python application in ActionScript."  Which, of course, would be easier than a from-scratch implementation, but would be largely a new effort.

Answer (score 2):

i havent done this but it shouldnt be to difficult to port python o silverlight because you should be able to use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and add `clr` references to your python code to start using the silverlight assemblies.